# How to change Mic source in TensorAudio?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, bluetooth, audio-recording, tensorflow.js

I have used Tensorflow [sample](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/task_library/audio_classifier#step_2_using_the_model) for audio classification.

```
AudioClassifier classifier = AudioClassifier.createFromFile(this, MODEL_FILE);
TensorAudio audioTensor = classifier.createInputTensorAudio();
AudioRecord record = classifier.createAudioRecord();
record.startRecording();
```

However, it seem recorder always picking the default Android Phones Mic even when I am connected with Bluetooth Mic (Earbud). Is there any way to let TensorAudio know the interesting mic source?

**Update:**

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
AudioDeviceInfo[] audioDevices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS);
AudioDeviceInfo bluetoothMic = null;
for (AudioDeviceInfo device : audioDevices) {
    if (device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO) {
        bluetoothMic = device;
        break;
    }
}
record.setPreferredDevice(bluetoothMic);
```

I got a way around and used the above code but in that case, classification does not work. No class detected. When I skip setPreferredDevice (default mic), it works fine. What is the reason?

Comment: Have you looked at whether a match has actually been found with `TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO`? It seems there's more than one type that your headset could be: [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo#constants_1).

Comment: Could you  check the AudioManager Configuration?

AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);  // Enable Bluetooth SCO
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();